# Conversion of IOB to spacy JSON taking alot of time ( IOB has 1 million lines)

Tags: nlp, google-colaboratory, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-transformers

I just want little guidance that there are 3 IOB file dev, test & train.
**Dev has 1 million lines.
Test has 4 million lines.
Train has 30 million.**
I am currently just converting dev file as of now because i wasn't sure whether is there any error or not in it.
(the IOB format is correct) It's been **over 3 hours** as of now can idea will this file work or shall I use something else.

I am **fine-tuning a bert model** using spacy in **google colab** the Runtime hardware chosen is **GPU** and the , and for reference I have followed this article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-fine-tune-bert-transformer-with-spacy-3-6a90bfe57647

I have followed the exact steps of the article.

I am not familiar with NLP domain neither do I have profound knowledge of pipelining. Can someone please help regarding this, it's really important.

Below i would attach the image regarding time and the statement executed for conversion.
[Image showing time elapsed and command executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lpUV.png)

Comment: I don't know the system but you can proceed like this: 1) do a test with a very small sample of data and debug any technical issue. 2) do the same process with a decent-size sample and based on this estimate the time for processing the full data. 3) based on the estimation, decide what's your next move: run the whole thing, use only a subset, buy more computing power (parallel processing), or change for a more efficient method.

Comment: This was also asked on the spaCy board. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8490#discussioncomment-913172